# Mark prime numbers in a range of numbers

Tags: python, primes

what I'm trying to do is to print the numbers `2-100` and mark the prime numbers with `-`

So, this should be the output:

```
2-
3-
4
5-
6
7-
8
9
10
.
.
.
100
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far. I'd expect it to be a `for` loop over a `range()` with code to test each number for primeness.

Comment: [What have you tried so far? What is not working about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Remember that **Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand site**. You may want to [edit] your question to include further information

Comment: sorry bout that i was actually trying to study the codes from this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619942/print-series-of-prime-numbers-in-python

and posted my question at the same time so when i get back it will be more easier for me to understand it

Comment: *"built in function"* - what you you expecting, `from laziness import two_to_100_with_primes_dashed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
primes = []

for candidate in range(2, 101):
    can_be_prime = True
    for prime in primes:
        if candidate % prime == 0:
            can_be_prime = False
            break
    if can_be_prime:
        primes.append(candidate)
        print "%d-" % candidate
    else:
        print candidate
```