# Im trying to make a code that prints out prime numbers, but it will spit out numbers such as 27 and 35

Tags: python

My code will spit out clearly non prime numbers and im trying to figure out why

when I run the code, it outputs the prime numbers, but also occasionally output non primes too

```
x = 1
a = 4
b=2
#prints 2
print(2)
#prints 3
print(3)
#whilst x is under 1000, the next section of code will run
while x < 100:
    #sets b to 2
    b = 2
    #will repeat aslong as b is less than a
    while b < a:
       #if a can be divided by b with no remainder
        if a % b == 0:
            #adds 1 to a
            a = a+1
            #if not will add one to b
        else:
            b = b+1
    print(a)
    a = a+1
    x = x+1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print series of prime numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619942/print-series-of-prime-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Compare your code to the [example code for Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division#Method).

Comment: To go off of @FredLarson's comment: I'd expect something like Trial Division or [Euler's Totient function](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Totient_function#Python) - your code as it currently stands looks to have a few gaps in establishing primality. You may also find the [Pseudocode for Wikipedia's Primality test article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode) helpful.

Comment: the logical problem with your code is that you're not trying all possible divisors, because you're failing to reset the divisor `b` to `2` after finding a divisor and moving on to the next `a` to try.

Comment: If the 2 numbers are in base 8, then you're fine :p.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

```
x = 1
a = 4
#prints 2
print(2)
#prints 3
print(3)
#whilst x is under 1000, the next section of code will run
while x < 100:
    #sets b to 2
    b = 2
    #will repeat aslong as b is less than a
    while b < a:
       #if a can be divided by b with no remainder
        if a % b == 0:
            #adds 1 to a
            a = a+1

            b = 2  # <-- Point is here!
            # When a and b are not coprimes, we have to go back
            # and look for all possible values for b again for this new value of a.

            #if not will add one to b
        else:
            b = b+1
    print(a)
    a = a+1
    x = x+1
```