# How do you find the first x prime numbers using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

```
def xPrimes(x) :
  y = 2
  while y < x :
      if isItPrime(y) == True :
        y += 1
      y += 1
  print(primes)
```

I am a beginner in python and I'm having trouble having the program do what's needed. I also don't fully understand what my program does. When I did xPrimes(5), it gave me [2,3,5] instead of [2,3,5,7,11]. My code prints all prime numbers UP to x instead of x prime numbers. I suspect that I need a counter but I don't know where to implement it.

Comment: Do you know what a prime number is? Would you know how to find the first 10 primes using just paper and pencil? You should make the function do the same thing you would do.

Comment: I have already implemented isItPrime to find and add all primes to the list of primes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print series of prime numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619942/print-series-of-prime-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep generating primes until you have `x` of them.  If you're returning a list of the results, your counter is the length of that list.

```
def xPrimes(x: int) -> List[int]:
    primes: List[int] = []
    y = 1
    while(len(primes) < x):
        y += 1
        if isItPrime(y):
            primes.append(y)
    return primes
```

Note that `y` is the prime number and `x` is the number of prime numbers and that these are *completely* different numbers.  :)

Comment: Yeah, note @BriK that your `xPrimes` took a number of primes `x` as an argument, but when you compared `y` to `x`, you were comparing the next prime _candidate_, not the number of primes already generated.

Answer (score 0):

What is primes here ?

you have to treat  x as counter and do not compare with y as y is prime number not a counter

instead you can do something like this

```
def xPrimes(x) :
  y = 2
  index = 0
  while index < x :
      if isItPrime(y) == True :
        y += 1
        index+= 1
      y += 1
  print(primes)
```

you can see, I have use index as counter and incremented it when I got prime number

Answer (score 0):

Homework is an adventure and chance to experiment!

First, you asked why `xPrimes(5)` gave you up to 5.  You stop your loop when y < x, and y goes up each time.   This shows you that you can get lost by using small variable names.  You could make your code look like this by just renaming things:

```
def primes_up_to_number(stop_at) :
  testing_number = 2
  while testing_number < stop_at :
      if isItPrime(testing_number) == True :
        testing_number += 1
      testing_number += 1
  print(primes)
```

This is confusing to me, as you can't get the output `[2, 3, 5]`.  When `testing_number` is 2, you add one to it, then add one again before you check `isItPrime` again, checking 4.  I am assuming `isItPrime` updates some global array `primes`.

I think you want to change the code and meaning from `stop_at` to `number_of_primes`.  If so, you should set a counter `number_of_primes_found = 0` at start of the function and add one to it each time you find a prime.  You should change the expression in the `while` loop to keep looping until that number of primes is found.

Have a great day!  Keep coding!  Keep notes.