# Encountering a recursion error for a Prime Indicator Python Code, Can it be rewritten to avoid error?

Tags: python, recursion

I have edited a piece of code which gives feedback for prime numbers on a large scale.  If the number is Prime it will result with a two digit number that ends in zero and it will show two of the same numbers.  For composite a number it will show two numbers that don't end in ZERO.  You would input the number in this fashion for a composite input range(2^8-2, 2^8)--output__54 54 or for a prime input range(2^7-2, 2^7)--output is __30 30

However I'm getting a recursive error.  Is there a way to rewrite the code, so that it does not use recursion or is there a work around the recursion.  I have tried increasing the sys overhead, but it did not work.

I noticed the recursion error when I tried 11.

Here is the code if someone can help me code it so recursion does not come up?

```
 def isPrime(n):

     isPrime = True

     def is_divisible(n,divisor):
         if n<(divisor-1)*divisor: return False
         if n%divisor==0: return True
         else:
             divisor += 1
             return is_divisible(n,divisor)

     if n==2:
         isPrime = True
     elif is_divisible(n,divisor=2):
         isPrime = False
     return isPrime

 def getNumPrimes(n):
     if n <= 2:
         return 0
     else:
         return isPrime(n-1) + getNumPrimes(n-1)
    
 for n in range(2**11-2,2**11):
     print(getNumPrimes(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the iterative variation of your algorithm. Instead of using recursion for both `is_divisible()` and `getNumPrimes()`, you can start from the bottom and work your way up.

There are a bunch of different ways to compute the number of primes less than or equal to a given number, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106237/11070463) benchmarks a handful of them that are written in python. Here's a paste of the quickest one:

```
def prime_count(n):
    """Counts number of prime numbers from 0 to n (inclusive)."""
    count = 0
    sieve = [True] * (n + 1)
    for p in range(2, n):
        if sieve[p]:
            count += 1
            for i in range(p, n + 1, p):
                sieve[i] = False
    return count
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to edit the code, you can increase the recursion limit in python using the `sys` module (although, there might be some unintended consequences, so proceed with caution):

```
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
>>> 3000

getNumPrimes(6000)
>>> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
getNumPrimes(6000)
>>> 783
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I did get to see 11 and it was 309 309, but it bombed out at 31, so thanks tho, maybe a rewrite of the code, its a shame cause, I think this code may indicate large primes.

Comment: I heard that if this code is iterative that it would work but I'm not that advanced a python.

Comment: @stellarwest updated, my post, see the iterative solution posted