# Python homework regarding prime numbers

Tags: python

My homework is simple, declare a function named `printPrimeNumbersTo` with a single argument named `to`

I created the skeleton of the code itself, however, I needed some help from the net.
GeeksforGeeks was the site where I "borrowed" a line of code, which I don't completely understand. (Site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-all-prime-numbers-in-an-interval/)

My code looks like this (I have comments on nearly every line, describing what I think that the line of code does):

```
def printPrimeNumbersTo(to):
   x = 0
   prime_list = [] # This was a string, however, I changed it to a list so I won't have to convert the numbers to a string every time I wanted to append it to the list
   for i in range(x, to + 1): # Create a for loop, using the function range an starting the loop at number 0. Add 1 to 'to', because range excludes the end integer
      if i == 0 or i == 1:
         continue
      else:
         for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1): # <--
            if i % j == 0: # If 'j' is divided by any number in the list and remainder is 0, then the number is not a prime number, which means I can break the loop
               break
            else:
               prime_list.append(i) # Append the prime number to the list
   return str(prime_list)[1:-1] # Returns '[2,3,5,7..]', I use the square brackets the get rid of the brackets themselves


print(printPrimeNumbersTo(7)) # >>> 2, 3, 5, 7
```

The one line I don't understand is marked with an arrow, it's the 8th line of the code.
Why am I dividing the number by 2? And then making it an integer? When I do the calculations, it works, but... where is the logic? Anybody help?

Comment: That is a terribly inefficient implementation with a failed optimization attempt. You can't learn by copying, in particular if you copy from geeksforgeeks, which is an awful place worth staying far away from.

Comment: A successful optimization would loop up to the square root, by the way. It is worth spending a few minutes on figuring out why.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo for the reply, however this does not answer my question. I am simply asking for someone to explain the logic to me. If I wanted to make the code more efficient, then sure, I would look into this deeper and possibly rewrite it. But this is just a **school project**, nothing that will be a part of some different code. There is no need for optimization. Maybe it would be a good exercise to write the functions optimized right away, so I will look into your solution.
If you have a felicitous answer for the question I asked, then I would be glad, if you could share it with me. Ty!

Comment: That's why they posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, I joined Stack Overflow moments ago, so I do not understand the value of the comment itself.

Comment: @Aakuho I attempted to provide value by inviting you to think about the problem instead of cheating.

Comment: A good learning exercise would be to try to condense the code as much as possible too, here is a one-line version for studying purposes: `printPrimeNumbersTo(to): return [n for n in range(1, to+1) if not any(n%i == 0 for i in range(2, n)) and n > 1]`

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, I appreciate it. Of course, everyone can copy paste, so I thank you for your answer and trying to help me instead of well.. help me.
dw about it though! The answer maybe came out wrong and more aggressive than it should have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest number which could possibly be an even factor of a number is the half of that number. The integer division operator `//` produces this number as an integer.

Because of how `range` works, the  ending index needs to be the desired number plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the number by 2 is done to reduce the number of iterations. For example, the number 12 you can divide it without a remainder by 1,2,3,4,6. Notice that there is no number bigger than (6) which is 12 / 2. And this goes on with all of the numbers.

```
 16   --->  1,2,8      no number bigger than its half (8)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to note:

1. the code needs to be indented correctly, in Python indentation matters as it forms the code blocks.
2. aside from this and specifically adressing the question: the `range` function that you refer to requires integers otherwise it would throw an typeerror like this: `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` .

```py
# this will throw an error
for i in range(1,  10.5):
    print(i)

# this will work
for i in range(1,  10):
    print(i)
```

So the reason why the line of code you queried was written like that was to ensure that the upper bound of the range was an integer.

You should also note that the `//` has a meaning, for example try this:

```py
x = 5//2
print(x)


y = 5/2
print(y)
```

x is the integer part only (`x=2`)

y is the full number (`y=2.5`)

In terms of implementaiton, there are a number of methods that would be better (suggested here):

[Print series of prime numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619942/print-series-of-prime-numbers-in-python)

Comment: The code was shifted due to a copy paste, I edited it and now it should be okay.
Now, I understand that I cannot put a float into the range function, however, that does not answer my question. I am unsure about this `i // 2 + 1` part. Mo Hesham said that this was made for performance boost, yet, when I delete the part and just keep it as `i + 1`, the code breaks.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the indentation.  Now running the code (in the modded question), i see that it does not find primes. The output that is returned with the code in the question is `5, 7, 7`....

Comment: That is correct, I was unsure why does that happen